# Why struct tags are not type names in C?

Tags: c

I am curious about the motivation for this behavior in C. Was it intentional or an accident?

```
struct tpoint // tpoint is not a type name
{
    int x, y;
};

typedef struct tpoint Point; // point is a type name.
```

I want to know why Ritchie or the standard committee chose this behaviour.

Comment: It's unlikely that Dennis Ritchie will be able to answer your question... If the answer isn't to be found in the Rationale document (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf), then this question probably isn't answerable...

Comment: I think you'll find that `struct tag` preceded `typedef` by a few years, and then it was all down to backwards compatibility.  C++ did do as you want.  Try hunting down 'Primeval C'.  I have a tar file 'v6root.tar' which contains source with lots of `struct` but nary a `typedef` in it.  That should be Unix V6 source code.  Unix V7 had `typedef`.

Comment: The most obvious reason is that with just `struct` and `union`, the language was still context-free - it wasn't until the later addition of `typedef` that the C language required a context-sensitive parser.

Answer (score 4):

It's a namespacing thing. This way, I can have `struct a`, `enum a`, `union a`, and none of them are ambiguous. It helps when designing frameworks which may have similar type names, but it can get confusing fast.

Comment: But I want to know why the standard committee or Dennis Ritchie chose this behavior.

Comment: That's certainly true, but I don't know that it's the definitive answer, or the original reasoning behind the decision by Messrs. Kernighan and Ritchie.

Comment: @Rayniery none of us are them - we can't tell you what they were thinking when they designed the language. We can only speculate, and speculation never leads to anything good.

Comment: That is what I really want to learn the original reasoing behind the decision. I already know that C has 4 different namespaces.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII, ¿but is it no documented somewhere?

Comment: @Rayniery unless you can talk with Brian Kernighan, have a seance with Dennis Ritchie or find something in the K&R book, I doubt you'll ever have a definitive answer.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the tag namespace is **shared** between structs, unions, and enums, i.e. you cannot have all three or even two of them defined with the same tag name.

Answer (score 0):

On reading [The Development of the C Language](http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/who/dmr/chist.html), when Dennis Ritchie discusses *Embryonic C* he describes his intention for a `struct`:

> I wanted the structure not merely to characterize an abstract object but also to describe a collection of bits that might be read from a directory.

The section is largely discussing how this idea led to the introduction of the "array <-> pointer equivalence". However, it does speak to the low level nature of C (a `struct` represents a "collection of bits").

In contrast, C++ uses a `struct` as a kind of synonym for `class`, but where everything is public. A `class` is really a concept in object oriented programming where it is more natural for its tag to be treated as a type.